# Google Drive and sync?

Tags: windows-7, google-docs, google-drive, offline-files

Two questions please:

1. *Where* are Google Drive offline docs stored in my computer? which *folder* ? (*when accessing `docs.google.com/offline`)
2. I have a text file in my Google Drive. When I click on it, I can *view* it only (no edit).

   The only option to edit is to export it to Google Docs, but now I have 2 files: the original text file and the the editable one. So now I have to sync *both* the regular file **AND** the version created by Google Docs. Is that the normal behavior?

Comment: Ugh. It's really best to only have one questions per...Question.

Comment: @AlEverett is it thaaaaat bad ? I don't think so. the 2 question aren't unrelated - they are very close.

Comment: By that logic, every question related to Google Drive ought to be rolled into one question. They are two separate questions with two separate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google Drive Offline files are stored inside of a database usually located under: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Default\IndexedDB\https_docs.google.com_0.indexeddb.leveldb

As such they are not directly accessible in the file system, for direct access to files in Google Drive use the normal sync client. I would hope this database stores the information in an encrypted format, but haven't verified whether or not this is the case.

Answer (score 2):

1. C:\Users\\Documents\Google Drive
2. If you want to use Google to edit the text file, then yes that is normal. If you just want to keep the .txt file, then only use your local computer application (i.e., notepad or similar) to edit the file. When you save it to the same location, Google drive will sync up the .txt file.

HTH.

Comment: it is not the location of the offline files. `C:\Users\\Documents\Google Drive`

Comment: this location is for the regular synced files. not the offline ones.

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Use your text editor to change the save location in that case.

Comment: it'll most likely be under your home AppData directory then - C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Drive or ..\Chrome; and from what i can see it might be in some format other than the simple file structure.

Comment: @John Ive searched in Total commander + hidden + sub folders and found the synced folder and the file SHORTCUT `meH.txt.gdoc` which its content is `{"url": "https://docs.google.com/document/d/11jxxxxxaYxKsCNDLow0l9T_Fu0/edit", "resource_id": "document:11jD2xxxxxxxViraYxKsCNDLow0l9T_Fu0"}`. couldnt find the file itself in offline mode.